# Cambiar paleta de colores en python

Tags: python, matplotlib

tengo el siguiente problema, las paletas de colores que trae `matplotlib` son predeterminadas, y estoy realizando el siguiente gráfico:

```
import pylab as plt 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
x1 = np.arange(1,13,1)
y1 = np.arange(0,24,1)
lev = np.arange(0,5,1)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x1,y1)
cs = plt.contourf(X,Y,z,lev[lev !=0], cmap= 'bwr' ,extend='both', alpha=0.5, )
plt.colorbar(cs, orientation = 'vertical',ticks = lev)
plt.quiver(X,Y,a,b)
plt.show()
```

lo que me genera un gráfico como este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que la parte azul sea blanca es decir que lo valores menores a 2 sean blancos y los mayores rojos, seria como tener un color que vaya desde blanco a rojo, un color secuencial pero solo de 2 tonos en este caso blanco y rojo,mi duda es si hay forma de crear un color divergente con esas caracterisiticas o si solo se pueden usar los predeterminados. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: los valores (z, a, b) no se encuentran en tu código por lo que es dificil replicar el resultado y dar una respuesta, pero si miras este [enlace](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html) puedes ver como crear un mapa de colores a tu medida

Comment: Gracias fue bastante útil